# pyinstaller no reonoce pywin32-ctypes

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Buen dia estoy intentando crear un ejecutable sin embargo pyinstaller siempre me da el mensaje de instalar pywin32-ctypes. Lo tengo ya instalado pero me sigue dando el mismo mensaje. tambien instale pywin32 y lo mismo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No tiene por qué resolverlo, pero descarta posibles causas, ejecuta lo siguiente y en ese orden en CMD: `py -3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip`; `py -3.8 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pywin32-ctypes`; `py -3.8 -m pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pyinstaller`;`py -3.8 -m PyInstaller links.py`

Comment: Gracias por responder, Acabo de utilizar los 4 y aun así no me sigue dando el mensaje de instalar pywin32-ctypes

Comment: Vale, el último  (`py -3.8 -m PyInstaller links.py`) te genera el mismo error ¿verdad? Si es así, al menos hemos descartado varias cosas. ¿Qué librería usas en tu proyecto?

Comment: esta usando : bs4,request,pandas,io,contextLib y tkinter

Comment: Logre resolverlo, Haciendo una instalacion directa con esto. `pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz`